# Bitrise giving error while uploading app to iTunes.ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements."

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, code-signing, bitrise

**ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value '' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload' is not supported."**

I am facing the above issue of uploading IPA through Bitrise to iTunes. It was working fine earlier and app also uploaded successfully. Issue started coming when I created new certificates after renewing old certificates.

I have tried creating a new provisioning profile after disabling the associate-domains in app id and enabled it again.
I also tried searching a lot but didn't found any perfect answer which can help me to resolve my error.

Why this problem is occurring and I am now not able to upload a new version.
Please see the attached screenshots for provisioning profile and app entitlements. [image][image] [image]

Comment: I'm also getting the same error

Comment: Me too.. facing the same issue.. found any solution yet?

Comment: Which Xcode version?

Answer (score 0):

This really is not a Bitrise Issue/Message. It's an ITC error message.
As a test, try using Xcode's Application Loader with the same Certs and Provisioning profile used in Bitrise and see if you can reproduce the error.
Also, the error: " Specifically, value '' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload' is not supported."
indicates to me that you are passing in "null" in your Payload.